# What Time Travel theory does Futurama follow?

Tags: futurama, time-travel

As the question states, what time travel theory does Futurama follow?

Some Time Travel Theories:

- Going back in Time then changing the Future creating a Paradox in which the event never happened resulting in the event going back in Time never happening therefore nothing changes(newest episode)
- Going back in Time to another Time-Line, able to do whatever without creating a paradox of the 1st theory I stated (similar to time-travelling so far into the future, that the Professor/Fry/Bender went into another universe or Fry's grandfather paradox?)
- Going back in Time, resulting in whatever you do will always happen(Bender destroying the 23rd(?) century when he stole a peace grant from Sweden between East and West side)

Which theory does Futurama follow?

Comment: [It's basically just this big ball of wibbly-wobbly time-wimey stuff.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeyWimeyBall)

Comment: Even more than most, I think Futurama follows the [MST3K Mantra](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MST3KMantra) "It's just a show; I should really just relax."  Not saying it's not a good question, but that I don't know that the writer allowed logical consistency to get in the way of the humor.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the events of *Bender's Big Score*, it depends on which type of time travel is used.  For example, the time-code discovered in that film is explicitly stated to provide paradox-resolving time travel, with the implication that other methods don't.

Comment: Some evidence to back up your claim: A paradox is created when Fry becomes his own grandfather in "Roswell That Ends Well", the method used to time travel was different than that of the time code.

Comment: @onewho:  Thank you very much!

Comment: @onewho Actually, since [The day Earth Stood Stupid](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Stupid) happened before [Roswell that Ends Well](http://theinfosphere.org/Roswell_that_Ends_Well) that's no paradox but a closed time loop.

Comment: @Zommuter - closed time loops are also known as "predestination paradoxes" or "bootstrap paradoxes" - the less dangerous form, of course, as they don't negate themselves, but they only happen because they already happened.  They aren't "grandfather paradoxes" (indeed, the one with Fry's ancestry came about due to an attempt to *avert* a literal version of a grandfather paradox), or anything similar, but they're still paradoxes.

Comment: @Darael Good point - maybe I'm a bit too literal with the word "paradox", only thinking of _unresolved_ ones (which would probably simply cause the entire multiverse to cease from ever having existed...)

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on this on the [Futurama Wiki](http://theinfosphere.org/Time_travel)

I wouldn't take it too seriously- although the writers show decent knowledge of scifi tropes and theoretical physics, they don't try all that hard to implement it flawlessly in the show or adhere to a consistent set of principles.

Comment: The "why should it necessarily follow any theory?" theory, in other words. :)